# Can you use reduce to return a boolean based off whether or not a series of digits is incrementing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce, higher-order-functions

So it seems fairly straightforward to write a function using a for loop to check if a given number's digits increment by 1. For example, passing the number 12345 should return true. But I'm curious if reduce can be used to achieve this by comparing each digit (assuming you've already split the number up into an array of digits) to the previous one and returning a boolean?

Comment: No, not directly. If you need `reduce` to access the previous digit, you cannot have returned a mere boolean - you will need a data structure with both.

Comment: Also, the downside of `reduce` is that you *have* to iterate the whole input, even if after the first pair it is already clear that the result is false. That's a pity.

Answer (score 1):

With reduce you can check if the current number is 1 more than the previous one.

Set an initial value for empty arrays. I've used `false`, but changing to `true` won't effect non empty arrays.

The 1st item should always return `true`, since we can't check it against any other number. The rest of the numbers you check vs. the previous one, and intersect with the previous value of the accumulator (`acc`):

```js
const fn = num => String(num)
  .split('')
  .reduce((acc, c, i, arr) => !i || acc && +c - 1 === +arr[i-1], false)

console.log(fn(12345)) // true
console.log(fn(112345)) // false
```

A better solution would to use `Array.every()` that will end, and return `false` as soon as any digit returns `false`. It will only return `true` if all digits are greater by one than the previous:

```js
const fn = num => String(num)
  .split('')
  .every((c, i, arr) => !i || +c - 1 === +arr[i-1])

console.log(fn(12345)) // true
console.log(fn(112345)) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to bail out early there is also `array.some`

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(!array.some((element, index, arr) => index>0?(element-arr[index-1]) !== 1:false));
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Honestly, folks,* ***why bother?"***  A simple loop just needs to march forward one digit at a time, bailing-out as soon as it finds a mismatch.  "Reduce" appears to be an extremely-academic question.

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a number, and its *digits* should increment by 1, then there are not that many solutions: the string representation of the number is always a substring of '0123456789'. This amounts to 10+8+7+..+1 possibilities, i.e. 46 (note that 0 cannot be combined). So the easiest is just:

```js
const isIncrementing = n => '0123456789'.includes(n);

// demo
console.log(isIncrementing(4567)); // true
console.log(isIncrementing(45567)); // false
console.log(isIncrementing(8901)); // false
console.log(isIncrementing(0)); // true
```

Using `reduce` is not called for, as it cannot bail out when it finds a pair of digits that violate the rule, but must continue to the very end.

Still, if it is required to use `reduce`, then I would let the accumulated value represent the previous digit when so far all digits were incrementing by 1, or make the accumulated value -2 otherwise. Then test that the final outcome is not -2.

```js
const isIncrementing = n => Array.from(String(n), Number)
                      .reduce((a, b) => a + 1 === b ? b : -2) >= 0; 

// demo
console.log(isIncrementing(4567)); // true
console.log(isIncrementing(45567)); // false
console.log(isIncrementing(8901)); // false
console.log(isIncrementing(0)); // true
```